# Type checking with Array of fixed values

Tags: typescript

I want to build a function that checks whether a value X is in another array, or return a default value. I'm using includes. Intuitively I'd say X should be unknown, or, say, `string | undefined`, but those fail with:

```
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '"nowrap" | "normal" | "pre-line"'.
```

So I use any, and now it works. But I find that weird. Why is my thinking wrong?

```
const wraps = ["nowrap", "wrap", "foo"]

function isBla(input: unknown):  typeof wraps[number] {
    if(wraps.includes(input)) {
        return input;
    }

    return "nowrap"
}
```

Aforementioned error. While 
`function isBla(input: any)` works fine.

Comment: I think the default typing for `array.includes()` assumes that `array` has some wide type and you are looking for some narrow value.  But you're doing the reverse... which is fine; it just isn't the anticipated use case.  If you are only reading from the array, it is safe to use a type assertion to widen its type (e.g., `(whitespaceVariants as unknown[]).includes(input)`) and the error will go away.

Comment: I'm not asking how to make the error go away. Casting feels like the cheap way out

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```js
whitespaceVariants.some(v => v===input)
```

but that seems redundant. casting seems good enough for me

```
whitespaceVariants.includes(v as (typeof whitespaceVariants)[number])
```

this is because `whitespaceVariants.includes` is inferred as type `(typeof whitespaceVariants)[number] => boolean`. This is useful for inferring general type like string or number but useless for inferring literal type unless [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520) is implemented